# Using javascript to replace the html content

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to replace the content of id='js' with javascript, but this is not working for me. here is the code.

```
<html>
    <head>
       <title></title>

       <script type="text/javascript">
            var ball = 0;
            function count_balls(ball){
                var count = ball + 1;
                return count;
                }
            document.getElementById('js').innerHTML = count_balls(0);
       </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id='js'>Result Here</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's working fine and returning 1. You can't call your parameters the same names as your global variables and expect that your code knows what to do with it. You call `count_balls(0)` so `ball` in `count_balls(ball)` will be `0`. `0 + 1 = 1` hence `count` = 1. To "fix" your code, change it to `count_balls() {` and `= count_balls();`. If you're trying to add `1` to `bar` you need to change `var count = ball + 1` to `ball++; return ball;`.

Comment: it is showing 'result here' on my browser. i don't know why

Comment: Ah yes. Sorry. What's actually happening is that you run your js before the element exists. Your javascript console would have told you this. Make a search for "javascript on document loaded".

Comment: Your script is executing before the '<p id="js">' is rendered on the page.

Comment: ohh Thanks... i just write the js code below my p tag and is working fine now..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the element is not initialized yet, it's not working.  You can either move the javascript to the end of the HTML (preferred) as shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>


</head>
<body>
    <p id='js'>Result Here</p>

       <script type="text/javascript">
        var ball = 0;
        function count_balls(ball){
            var count = ball + 1;
            return count;
            }

        document.getElementById('js').innerHTML = count_balls(0);
   </script>
</body>
```

Or you can use [jquery document.ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to achieve the same thing.